# How to automate SARIMA model for time series forecasting?

Tags: python, time-series, data-science, forecasting

I am trying to find the right parameters for p,d,q in time series forecasting using SARIMA. I need to forecast house prices for 1000 zip codes. The problem is that grid search takes too much time and I can't manually look at ACF/PACF for each zip code as I need to automate it.

I tried using grid search for 8 different combinations of parameters and used the best set of params based on AIC.

```
p = d = q = range(0, 2)
#d = range(0, 2)
pdq = list(itertools.product(p, d, q))
seasonal_pdq = [(x[0], x[1], x[2], 12) for x in list(itertools.product(p, d, q))]
parameters = []
for param in pdq:
    for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
        try:
            model = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(y_new,method='css',
                                            order=param,
                                            seasonal_order=param_seasonal,
                                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                                            enforce_invertibility=False)
            results = model.fit()
            #print('ARIMA{}x{}12 - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, results.aic))
        except:
            continue
        aic = results.aic
        parameters.append([param,param_seasonal,aic])
result_table = pd.DataFrame(parameters)
result_table.columns = ['parameters','parameters_seasonal','aic']
    # sorting in ascending order, the lower AIC is - the better
result_table = result_table.sort_values(by='aic', ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
```

I can't get a model which can beat the naive forecast. Can you give me some direction on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the **pyramid** library, which would automate the selection of p, d, q parameters. You would need to manipulate the data sufficiently so as to feed in 1000 time series, but here is an example of how it would be run on a single time series.

Suppose we have a dataset of maximum recorded daily temperature over time, and the objective is to automate the selection of p, d, q parameters for ARIMA. This could be achieved as follows:

```
from pyramid.arima.stationarity import ADFTest
adf_test = ADFTest(alpha=0.05)
adf_test.is_stationary(series)
train, test = series[1:741], series[742:927]
train.shape
test.shape
plt.plot(train)
plt.plot(test)
plt.title("Training and Test Data")
plt.show()
```

[image: training and test]

As you can see, the ARIMA model selection itself is based on the configuration with the lowest AIC in this case:

```
>>> Arima_model=auto_arima(train, start_p=1, start_q=1, max_p=8, max_q=8, start_P=0, start_Q=0, max_P=8, max_Q=8, m=12, seasonal=True, trace=True, d=1, D=1, error_action='warn', suppress_warnings=True, random_state = 20, n_fits=30)
Fit ARIMA: order=(1, 1, 1) seasonal_order=(0, 1, 0, 12); AIC=-667.202, BIC=-648.847, Fit time=3.710 seconds
Fit ARIMA: order=(0, 1, 0) seasonal_order=(0, 1, 0, 12); AIC=-270.700, BIC=-261.522, Fit time=0.354 seconds
Fit ARIMA: order=(1, 1, 0) seasonal_order=(1, 1, 0, 12); AIC=-625.446, BIC=-607.090, Fit time=2.365 seconds
Fit ARIMA: order=(0, 1, 1) seasonal_order=(0, 1, 1, 12); AIC=-1090.370, BIC=-1072.014, Fit time=7.584 seconds
Fit ARIMA: order=(0, 1, 1) seasonal_order=(1, 1, 1, 12); AIC=-1088.657, BIC=-1065.712, Fit time=10.024 seconds
Fit ARIMA: order=(0, 1, 1) seasonal_order=(0, 1, 0, 12); AIC=-653.939, BIC=-640.172, Fit time=1.733 seconds
Fit ARIMA: order=(0, 1, 1) seasonal_order=(0, 1, 2, 12); AIC=-1087.889, BIC=-1064.944, Fit time=25.853 seconds
Fit ARIMA: order=(0, 1, 1) seasonal_order=(1, 1, 2, 12); AIC=-1087.188, BIC=-1059.655, Fit time=31.205 seconds
Fit ARIMA: order=(1, 1, 1) seasonal_order=(0, 1, 1, 12); AIC=-1105.233, BIC=-1082.288, Fit time=10.266 seconds
Fit ARIMA: order=(1, 1, 0) seasonal_order=(0, 1, 1, 12); AIC=-887.349, BIC=-868.994, Fit time=9.558 seconds
Fit ARIMA: order=(1, 1, 2) seasonal_order=(0, 1, 1, 12); AIC=-1086.931, BIC=-1059.397, Fit time=11.649 seconds
Fit ARIMA: order=(0, 1, 0) seasonal_order=(0, 1, 1, 12); AIC=-724.814, BIC=-711.047, Fit time=4.372 seconds
Fit ARIMA: order=(2, 1, 2) seasonal_order=(0, 1, 1, 12); AIC=-1085.480, BIC=-1053.358, Fit time=17.619 seconds
Fit ARIMA: order=(1, 1, 1) seasonal_order=(1, 1, 1, 12); AIC=-1072.933, BIC=-1045.400, Fit time=13.924 seconds
Fit ARIMA: order=(1, 1, 1) seasonal_order=(0, 1, 2, 12); AIC=-1102.926, BIC=-1075.392, Fit time=28.082 seconds
Fit ARIMA: order=(1, 1, 1) seasonal_order=(1, 1, 2, 12); AIC=-1102.342, BIC=-1070.219, Fit time=35.426 seconds
Fit ARIMA: order=(2, 1, 1) seasonal_order=(0, 1, 1, 12); AIC=-1010.837, BIC=-983.303, Fit time=8.926 seconds
Total fit time: 222.656 seconds
>>> 
>>> Arima_model.summary()
<class 'statsmodels.iolib.summary.Summary'>
"""
                                 Statespace Model Results                                 
==========================================================================================
Dep. Variable:                                  y   No. Observations:                  740
Model:             SARIMAX(1, 1, 1)x(0, 1, 1, 12)   Log Likelihood                 557.617
Date:                            Thu, 14 Mar 2019   AIC                          -1105.233
Time:                                    16:33:59   BIC                          -1082.288
Sample:                                         0   HQIC                         -1096.379
                                            - 740                                         
Covariance Type:                              opg                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
intercept   1.359e-06   6.75e-06      0.201      0.840   -1.19e-05    1.46e-05
ar.L1          0.1558      0.034      4.575      0.000       0.089       0.223
ma.L1         -0.9847      0.013    -75.250      0.000      -1.010      -0.959
ma.S.L12      -0.9933      0.092    -10.837      0.000      -1.173      -0.814
sigma2         0.0118      0.001     11.259      0.000       0.010       0.014
===================================================================================
Ljung-Box (Q):                       54.38   Jarque-Bera (JB):              3179.66
Prob(Q):                              0.06   Prob(JB):                         0.00
Heteroskedasticity (H):               0.77   Skew:                            -1.46
Prob(H) (two-sided):                  0.04   Kurtosis:                        12.82
===================================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Covariance matrix calculated using the outer product of gradients (complex-step).
```

If you are familiar with R, you can also use the **auto.arima** command. In fact, I would recommend doing so, as there are occasions where it might give you a better automated configuration than in Pyramid (which was developed more recently).

That said, **pyramid** would help to automate things greatly for you.

Comment: Thanks Micheal. I got pyramid to work. It has an auto arima function which runs the grid search in a more efficient way.I gave seasonal=True and seasonality was handled as well. It was a small improvement but I was able to beat the naive forecast

Comment: No problem Manasa. If you feel the above answered your question adequately, then you might kindly accept the answer by clicking on the green checkmark.

Comment: I'm trying your way and got error NameError: name 'auto_arima' is not defined

Comment: from pyramid.arima import auto_arima